# React functional component: TypeError: handleFlagChange is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Consider the following:

I have a parent functional component with a nested child component,

```
function Parent(){
  const [isFlagTrue, setIsFlagIsTrue] = useState(false);

    const handleFlagChange = (bool) => setIsFlagIsTrue(bool)

    useEffect(() => {

    console.log("isFlagTrue ", isFlagTrue);
 }, [isFlagTrue])

  return (
    <Child handleFlagChange={handleFlagChange} />
  )
}
```

In the Child I'm making an async call to populate a data-table;

```
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';


function Child({handleFlagChange}) {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const componentIsMounted = useRef(true)
    const [rows, setRows] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {

        if (currentProductItem && currentProductItem.value != null) {
            
               dispatch(getClientVariables(currentProductItem.value)).then(r => {
                rawData.current.Rows = r.payload;
                dispatch(getClientVariableTypesAll(currentProductItem.value)).then(r => {

                    rawData.current.ClientDataVariableTypes = r.payload.map(r => {
                        return {
                            value: r.ClientDataVariableTypeID,
                            label: r.ClientDataVariableTypeName
                        }
                    });;
                    setRows(rawData.current.Rows);
                    console.log('rawData', rawData);

                });
            });
        }
    }, [currentProductItem, justSavedNewVariableTypes, justSavedGrid]);

}

    useEffect(() => {
    console.log("typeof handleFlagChange ", typeof handleFlagChange);

    console.log("rows ", rows);

    // if (componentIsMounted.current) {
    //  var flag = rows.some(item => item.ClientDataVariableTypeName == null)
    //  handleFlagChange(flag)
    // }

    if (Array.isArray(rows) && typeof handleFlagChange != 'undefined') {
        console.log("foo ");
        var flag = rows.some(item => item.ClientDataVariableTypeName == null)
        handleFlagChange(flag)
    }
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
        componentIsMounted.current = false
    }
},[])
    
   ....other code & rendering    
    
}
```

I am expecting the `isFlagTrue` console in the useEffect of the parent to fire when the rows have been validated in the child by the return value of the `some` function on the array of rows.

I have tried two solutions one is insuring the `<Child/>` is mounted (and having the data call being full-filled) by setting a ref to true using `useRef()`.

In Child:
const componentIsMounted = useRef(true)

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("typeof handleFlagChange ", typeof handleFlagChange);


     if (componentIsMounted.current) {
       var flag = rows.some(item => item.ClientDataVariableTypeName == null)
       handleFlagChange(flag)
      }

}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
        componentIsMounted.current = false
    }
},[])
```

But I get `TypeError: handleFlagChange is not a function`

So then I tried:

```
useEffect(() => {
        console.log("typeof handleFlagChange ", typeof handleFlagChange);

        if (componentIsMounted.current && typeof handleFlagChange != 'undefined' && typeof handleFlagChange != 'undefined') {
            console.log("foo ");
            var flag = rows.some(item => item.ClientDataVariableTypeName == null)
            handleFlagChange(flag)
        }
    }, []);
```

But that yields:

```
typeof handleFlagChange  undefined. <---In the Child
isFlagTrue  false <--- In Parent
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `handleFlagChange !== undefined` or `!!handleFlagChange` to check if `handleFlagChange` is defined or not, not `typeof`.

Comment: Change condition as `if (componentIsMounted.current && handleFlagChange)`

Comment: @LukasBach Thanks for responding! That didn't work.

Comment: @RahulKumar Thanks my friend, but that didn't work as well.

Comment: I would recommend making an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to narrow down the scope of the problem, and to ensure you're running the code you think you are. In the scenario provided I don't see any obvious way for `handleFlagChange` to be undefined.

Comment: Unrelated, but if you're specifically checking for `undefined` just write `foo === undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you consider using a default value for the function and let the normal flow of React do yours?

```
function Child({handleFlagChange = () => {}})
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: That's a great idea, let me try this.

Comment: Sure, you can also use PropTypes, Child.defaultProps = { handleFlagChange: () => {} }

Comment: @AntonioPavicevac-Ortiz It isn't really--this ignores an underlying problem or misunderstanding and leaves you with a non-functional `handleFlagChange`. It'd be better to isolate and fix the underlying problem, for example, do you have *other* `<Child>` components in use that aren't being passed a valid `handleFlagChange`, and if so, why?

Comment: Is it really and underlying problem? I'm used to adding fallbacks to prevent this scenarios. Please let me know, because in that case I'll have to do a huge refactor, even at work.

Comment: @FelipeCandalCampos IMO it's *clearly* an underlying problem: in the code posted I don't see how it could be `undefined` because it's passed directly in. That's why I suggested making an isolated [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to prove that what is happening is actually happening, where the OP thinks it's happening. If you're regularly adding fallbacks it means you don't trust your own code. *Deliberately* not providing values is an entirely different scenario, and fallbacks  may or may not be the best solution.

Comment: @FelipeCandalCampos  Yeah Dave is right. I just been at this a while and at first blush I thought that would work, but that's just assigning that to a function type, but overwriting the parents version.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I always thought that it was the regular mounting flow of React, An MVCE would be great so we can all test it. @AntonioPavicevac-Ortiz

Comment: @FelipeCandalCampos I'm not sure what you mean by the "regular mounting flow" or how it matters--there's a property being passed in; that property is available as soon as the component is instantiated.

Comment: Yeah, never mind, if you could provide and MVCE so we can all test it @AntonioPavicevac-Ortiz. I don't really know how to explain it, but if I didn't add fallbacks, sometimes my code crashes, I'm lately more into Go and APIs, so I'm probably really cofused.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a typescript error saying that the type of handleFlagChange is not known in child Component.

You have 2 option here:

First, declare type of each prop at first and then use it in function:

```
 type PropsType = { handleFlagChange: () => void }
    
 function Child({handleFlagChange}: PropsType)
```

Or try to add specific type in the function itself:

```
function Child({handleFlagChange: () => void})
```

where `() => void` being the type of handleFlagChange function.

Comment: There's no TypeScript here, and if it was a TypeScript issue, it would appear during transpilation, not at runtime.

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks for correcting it @DaveNewton